# Sitecore: Allowing a user/role to publish

Tags: publishing, sitecore

I'm in the process of implementing a workflow in Sitecore, and for that I have setup several different users with roles, where the security for the roles dictates the workflow process (nothing unusual).

One of these roles is a "CMS Publisher", and its job is to be last in the review process and to publish the item once it is accepted. The problem is that in the Publish tab, there is no "Publish" button. I know that it is possible to Auto-Publish items once they get into a final state, but I would like for this role to have access to that button as well. I figured it's a security setting on a content item somewhere, but I've searched the core/master database to no avail and the sdn provides zero information on this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your "CMS Publisher" role a 'member of' the built in "Sitecore Client Publishing" role and see if the button shows up.

Comment: This looks correct to me.  More information on the built-in Sitecore Client roles can be found on p7 of the Sitecore Security Reference document available on the SDN.

Comment: This gave me the results I needed. It was a strange situation since the client roles weren't visible inside Sitecore. I had to create them in our member database, then followed this, and everything worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting the web.config file that will require the Sitecore Client Publishing role to have both read and write access in order to publish an item. This setting is Publishing.CheckSecurity.

You can read a full explanation [here](http://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/publishing-security-basics/).